# Android SDK is not with eclipse

Tags: android

Before few times i have seen the link for download android sdk which is included Eclipse and now it is with android studio. Why google removed that? if anyone has right information then please share here or where can i download that old sdk then?

Comment: old sdk ? what for? download stand alone SDK then download Eclipse from eclipse.org then install ADT from Help->Install New Software ... problem is why there is no Android Studio without SDK ...

Comment: Follow the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. They are not longer providing the bundled version of Eclipse. Still the plugin is available **[here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)**

Please, note that the official ide is now Android Studio:

> Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android
>   Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to
>   Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving
>   projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.